# Getting Nginx working with /index.php/something

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to migrate from Apache to Nginx. I'm using Nginx 1.8.1 and PHP 5.6

Apache accepts URLs like this:

```
domain.com/site/index.php/something
```

and calls index.php script with the parameter /something. This is how my Wordpress works but there are other scripts that rely on.

For example I can do this:

```
domain.com/path/script.php/someparameter
```

How can I get this working in Nginx?

EDIT:
I found the solution for Wordpress:

```
location /blog/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
}
```

But what is a general solution for all scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a rewrite.

For example rewrite all PHP scripts with trailing `/`:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.+\.php)(/.+) /$1?$2;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```